# Is there a way in F# to chain computation?

Tags: f#

I would like to create a chain of expressions and any of them can fail when the computation should just stop.

With Unix pipes it is usually like this:

```
bash-3.2$ echo && { echo 'a ok'; echo; }  && { echo 'b ok'; echo; }
a ok

b ok
```

When something fails the pipeline stops:

```
echo && { echo 'a ok'; false; }  && { echo 'b ok'; echo; }

a ok
```

I can handle Optionals but my problem is that I might want to do multiple things in each branch:

```
let someExternalOperation = callToAnAPI()
match someExternalOperation with
| None -> LogAndStop()
| Some x -> LogAndContinue()
```

Then I would like to keep going with other API calls and only stop if there is an error.

Is there something like that in F#?

Update1:

What I am trying to do is calling out to external APIs. Each call can fail. Would be nice to try to retry but not required.

Comment: There are a couple of options - but what is best depends on what is the actual situation that you are dealing with. I think that answering the question abstractly might lead you into a poor direction, so it would be good to know more about your specific situation.

Comment: I have updated the question. I think I could use Fsharpx maybe {} for this.

Comment: Is using F#'s type system to prevent invalid or otherwise "bad" data from polluting your pipeline something you're trying to accomplish? Or, rather, why are you choosing F# for this? I would choose F# so that I was confident in the quality of the results. I'd start with taking API results and using something like active patterns to match them to DU values. But that depends heavily on what kind of data you're expecting to see, which is why we do need more information to help answer your question.

Comment: check out https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/

Comment: Second @KeithNicholas comment. If you like that idea, someone here might write a summary as an answer.

Comment: @Guran I would caution that is a intro to what can be done in terms of "chaining", but you can do a whole lot more and customize the "chaining" to be whatever you want.

Comment: @KeithNicholas Yeah, that's why I did not simply use those ideas for an answer. More as an inspiration as to how to refine the question.
I use chained binds for http calls a lot, but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the F# `Async` and `Result` types together to represent the results of each API Call.  You can then use the `bind` functions for those types to build a workflow in which you only continue processing when the previous calls were successful.  In order to make that easier, you can wrap the `Async<Result<_,_>>` you would be working with for each api call in its own type and build a module around `binding` those results to orchestrate a chained computation.  Here's a quick example of what that would look like:

First, we would lay out the type `ApiCallResult` to wrap `Async` and `Result`, and we would define `ApiCallError` to represent HTTP error responses or exceptions:

```ml
open System
open System.Net
open System.Net.Http

type ApiCallError =
| HttpError of (int * string)
| UnexpectedError of exn

type ApiCallResult<'a> = Async<Result<'a, ApiCallError>>
```

Next, we would create a module to work with `ApiCallResult` instances, allowing us to do things like `bind`, `map`, and `return` so that we can process the results of a computation and feed them into the next one.

```ml
module ApiCall =
    let ``return`` x : ApiCallResult<_> =
        async { return Ok x }

    let private zero () : ApiCallResult<_> = 
        ``return`` []

    let bind<'a, 'b> (f: 'a -> ApiCallResult<'b>) (x: ApiCallResult<'a>) : ApiCallResult<'b> =
        async {
            let! result = x
            match result with
            | Ok value -> 
                return! f value
            | Error error ->
                return Error error
        }

    let map f x = x |> bind (f >> ``return``)

    let combine<'a> (acc: ApiCallResult<'a list>) (cur: ApiCallResult<'a>) =
        acc |> bind (fun values -> cur |> map (fun value -> value :: values))

    let join results =
        results |> Seq.fold (combine) (zero ())
```

Then, you would have a module to simply do your API calls, however that works in your real scenario.  Here's one that just handles GETs with query parameters, but you could make this more sophisticated:

```ml
module Api =
    let call (baseUrl: Uri) (queryString: string) : ApiCallResult<string> =
        async {
            try
                use client = new HttpClient()
                let url = 
                    let builder = UriBuilder(baseUrl)
                    builder.Query <- queryString
                    builder.Uri
                printfn "Calling API: %O" url
                let! response = client.GetAsync(url) |> Async.AwaitTask
                let! content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
                if response.IsSuccessStatusCode then
                    let! content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
                    return Ok content
                else
                    return Error <| HttpError (response.StatusCode |> int, content)
            with ex ->
                return Error <| UnexpectedError ex
        }

    let getQueryParam name value =
        value |> WebUtility.UrlEncode |> sprintf "%s=%s" name
```

Finally, you would have your actual business workflow logic, where you call multiple APIs and feed the results of one into another.  In the below example, anywhere you see `callMathApi`, it is making a call to an external REST API that may fail, and by using the `ApiCall` module to bind the results of the API call, it only proceeds to the next API call if the previous call was successful.  You can declare an operator like `>>=` to eliminate some of the noise in the code when binding computations together:

```ml
module MathWorkflow =
    let private (>>=) x f = ApiCall.bind f x

    let private apiUrl = Uri "http://api.mathjs.org/v4/" // REST API for mathematical expressions

    let private callMathApi expression =
        expression |> Api.getQueryParam "expr" |> Api.call apiUrl

    let average values =        
        values 
        |> List.map (sprintf "%d") 
        |> String.concat "+" 
        |> callMathApi
        >>= fun sum -> 
                sprintf "%s/%d" sum values.Length 
                |> callMathApi

    let averageOfSquares values =
        values 
        |> List.map (fun value -> sprintf "%d*%d" value value)
        |> List.map callMathApi
        |> ApiCall.join
        |> ApiCall.map (List.map int)
        >>= average
```

This example uses the Mathjs.org API to compute the average of a list of integers (making one API call to compute the sum, then another to divide by the number of elements), and also allows you to compute the average of the squares of a list of values, by calling the API asynchronously for each element in the list to square it, then joining the results together and computing the average.  You can use these functions as follows (I added a `printfn` to the actual API call so it logs the HTTP requests):

Calling average:

```ml
MathWorkflow.average [1;2;3;4;5] |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Outputs:

```
Calling API: http://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=1%2B2%2B3%2B4%2B5
Calling API: http://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=15%2F5
[<Struct>]
val it : Result<string,ApiCallError> = Ok "3"
```

Calling averageOfSquares:

```ml
MathWorkflow.averageOfSquares [2;4;6;8;10] |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Outputs:

```
Calling API: http://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=2*2
Calling API: http://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=4*4
Calling API: http://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=6*6
Calling API: http://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=8*8
Calling API: http://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=10*10
Calling API: http://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=100%2B64%2B36%2B16%2B4
Calling API: http://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=220%2F5
[<Struct>]
val it : Result<string,ApiCallError> = Ok "44"
```

Ultimately, you may want to implement a custom Computation Builder to allow you to use a computation expression with the `let!` syntax, instead of explicitly writing the calls to `ApiCall.bind` everywhere.  This is fairly simple, since you already do all the real work in the `ApiCall` module, and you just need to make a class with the appropriate Bind/Return members:

```ml
type ApiCallBuilder () =
    member __.Bind (x, f) = ApiCall.bind f x
    member __.Return x = ApiCall.``return`` x
    member __.ReturnFrom x = x
    member __.Zero () = ApiCall.``return`` ()

let apiCall = ApiCallBuilder()
```

With the `ApiCallBuilder`, you could rewrite the functions in the `MathWorkflow` module like this, making them a little easier to read and compose:

```ml
    let average values =        
        apiCall {
            let! sum =
                values 
                |> List.map (sprintf "%d") 
                |> String.concat "+" 
                |> callMathApi

            return! 
                sprintf "%s/%d" sum values.Length
                |> callMathApi
        }        

    let averageOfSquares values =
        apiCall {
            let! squares = 
                values 
                |> List.map (fun value -> sprintf "%d*%d" value value)
                |> List.map callMathApi
                |> ApiCall.join

            return! squares |> List.map int |> average
        }
```

These work as you described in the question, where each API call is made independently and the results feed into the next call, but if one call fails the computation is stopped and the error is returned.  For example, if you change the URL used in the example calls here to the `v3` API ("http://api.mathjs.org/v3/") without changing anything else, you get the following:

```
Calling API: http://api.mathjs.org/v3/?expr=2*2
[<Struct>]
val it : Result<string,ApiCallError> =
  Error
    (HttpError
       (404,
        "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /v3/</pre>
</body>
</html>
"))
```